# Read attribute values in reactive form submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, angular

I have a reactive form containing input having attribute in it:

```
<input type="text" [attr.data-challengeId]="value.id" [formControlName]="value.label">
```

On submitting form I get only value, but I need the attribute value too.
Tried adding tag reference #inputTag, but that doesn't help.
Let me know how I can read the attribute inside tags.

Comment: Can you please be more specific of which attribute you want ?

Comment: And reactive forms are supposed to bind the UI-form model with the non-UI data model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to our problem is to create input hidden

```
<input type="hidden" name='data-challengeId' [value]="value.id" ngModel>
```

Comment: I know the  answer is a work around, but it solved my issue and I am closing this question by accepting your answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks  @MichaelPhilips